# Pass Trigger.old to constructor

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger

I am not able to pass Trigger.old to constructor,

**Trigger**

```
trigger Test on Student_Details__c (after insert, after update,after delete) {


            studentupdatehandler studobj = new studentupdatehandler(trigger.new ,trigger.old);
            if(trigger.isinsert)
            {
            studobj.afterinsert();
            }

            if(trigger.isdelete)
            {
            studobj.afterdelete();
            }

           if(trigger.isupdate)
           {
           studobj.afterupdate();
           }    
    }
```

**TriggernHandler**

```
public class studentupdatehandler{

     set<id> newDeptids = new set<id>();  
     set<id> oldDeptids = new set<id>();  


     public studentupdatehandler(student_details__c[] newstudentlist , student_details__c[] oldstudentList){


        for(student_Details__c record: newstudentlist)
        {
          newDeptids.add(record.Department__c);
        }
         for(student_Details__c record: oldstudentlist)
        {
          oldDeptids.add(record.Department__c);
        }



     }



     public void afterinsert() {

        list<department__c> newdeptlist = [select id,name,no_of_students__c,(select id from student_details__r) from department__c where id in:newDeptids];

        toinsert(newdeptlist);


 } 


     public void afterdelete() {

        list<department__c> olddeptlist = [select id,name,no_of_students__c,(select id from student_details__r) from department__c where id in:oldDeptids];

        toupdatedelete(olddeptlist);


 }




    public void afterupdate() {

        list<department__c> newdeptlist = [select id,name,no_of_students__c,(select id from student_details__r) from department__c where id in:newDeptids];
        toinsert(newdeptlist);


        list<department__c> odeptlist= [select id,name,no_of_students__c,(select id from student_details__r) from department__c where id in:oldDeptids];
        toupdatedelete(odeptlist);  

}

Public void toinsert(department__c[] deptlist ){

        for(department__c dept : deptlist){

               if (dept.Name == 'CSE')
                   {
                   dept.no_of_students__c = dept.no_of_students__c +1;
                   }
               else if (dept.Name == 'ECE')
                {
                   dept.no_of_students__c = dept.no_of_students__c +1;
                   }
               else if (dept.Name == 'IT')
                   {
                   dept.no_of_students__c = dept.no_of_students__c +1;
                   }

                else if (dept.Name == 'EEE')
                {
                   dept.no_of_students__c = dept.no_of_students__c +1;
                   }

            }                 
   update deptlist;      
        } 

Public void toupdatedelete(department__c[] odeptlist ){


        for(department__c dept : odeptlist){

               if (dept.Name == 'CSE')
                   {
                   dept.no_of_students__c = dept.no_of_students__c -1;
                    }

                else if (dept.Name == 'ECE')
                {
                   dept.no_of_students__c = dept.no_of_students__c -1;
                   }
                else if (dept.Name == 'IT')
                   {
                   dept.no_of_students__c = dept.no_of_students__c -1;
                   }

                else if (dept.Name == 'EEE')
                {
                   dept.no_of_students__c = dept.no_of_students__c -1;
                   }

            } 



  update odeptlist; 
}
```

}

The error is on line *for(student_Details__c record: oldstudentlist)* , the error is

> Error: Invalid Data.  Review all error messages below to correct your
>   data. Apex trigger Test caused an unexpected exception, contact your
>   administrator: Test: execution of AfterInsert caused by:
>   System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object:
>   Class.studentupdatehandler.: line 10, column 1

Can trigger.old not be passed in a constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have one constructor for `after insert`, `after update`, `after delete` actions. But `Trigger.old` is only available in update and delete triggers. That is why it fails on `after insert` with null pointer exception.

Refer to [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm)

Answer (score 0):

try to change your code like this, so that it will not fail on insertion .

```
 trigger Test on Student_Details__c (after insert, after update,after delete) {
     studentupdatehandler studobj ;
    if(Trigger.isafter && Trigger.isupdate || Trigger.isafter && Trigger.isdelete )         
    studobj = new studentupdatehandler(trigger.new ,trigger.old);
    else
    studobj = new studentupdatehandler(trigger.new , new list<Student_Details__c>());


            if(trigger.isinsert)
            {
            studobj.afterinsert();
            }

            if(trigger.isdelete)
            {
            studobj.afterdelete();
            }

           if(trigger.isupdate)
           {
           studobj.afterupdate();
           }    
    }
```